# HC-SR501 PIR sensor range issue

Tags: relay, pir

I installed a PIR sesnor for multiple rooms in my house and they worked perfectly for the past six months.  I recently noticed a change in their performance.  They barely detect my movement even if I'm directly below them. The only thing changed is the ambient temperature.

Could that be the reason for the poor performance?

I tried replacing the sensors with new ones but with the same issue for all rooms.

I even tried to power the PIR sensor with separate buck converter to make sure it gets enough current but no luck.

Here is the setup I'm using:

[image]

> **Observation: I noticed the detector works as expected at night time.**

Comment: Have you tried making it more sensitive by adjusting the left potentiometer? See the description [here](https://lastminuteengineers.com/pir-sensor-arduino-tutorial/)

Comment: Are you sure that, with the change in seasons, the sun isn’t directly shining on the sensors?

Comment: How hot is it in those rooms?

Comment: @StarCat Yes It's at max settings

Comment: @MarkLeavitt No it is not exposed to the sun. I have dropped ceiling and al electrnoics and wire are above it which gets really hot like a Sona.

Comment: @jcaron I didn't measure but I would say in the range of (40s C).

Comment: PIR sensors work by sensing variations in the difference in temperature between the human body and the rest of the environment. If the environment has a temperature close to that of the human body, it will not work well (if at all). You’ll need different types of sensors to detect presence if it routinely gets that hot.